# choose proper service, spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a web application in java using spring.
I encountered a problem with choosing a service
I have interface Car and some implementation like Ferarri, Mercedes etc which I get as a parametr in some class. In this class I have to call method of the appropriate service

```
  class someClass {

    public sendCar (Car car) {
         // send car to a proper car service
         // [service].send(car)

    }
```

and I have various car service

```
   FerrariCarService {
        ....
   }

   MercedesCarService {
        ....
   }
```

etc

How to do this well ? I tried using EventBus from Guava, but I have a problem with automatically registering all services. Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something the [factory pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) can solve. Create a car service factory and send in the car as a parameter and have the factory return the appropriate car service.

```
public class CarServiceFactory 
{
     public CarService getCarService(Car car) 
     {
           if (car instanceof Ferrari) {
                 return new FerrariService();
           }
           ...
     } 
}
```

Then your FerrariCarService and MercedesCarService will need to implement CarService.